# Apparent counterexample to the Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was assigned the following differential equation with initial value condition:

$$dy/dx=xy^{1/2}, y(2)=1.$$

Then I found out that the following functions, $y(x)=x^4/16$ and $(x^2-8)^2/16$, are solutions to this equation.

Why does not this contradict the uniqueness of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

The statement of the theorem which I'm using is the following: http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec4.pdf

Is this formulation wrong?

Comment: What are the assumptions of the Picard-Lindelof theorem? Does $xy^{1/2}$ satisfy those assumptions?

Comment: @Jonas It seems to be the case, http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec4.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y(x)=(x^2-8)^2/16$ does not have the property that $y^{1/2}=(x^2-8)/4$, because that is a negative value when $x$ is near $2$.

So $y'=x(x^2-8)/4 = -xy^{1/2}$ when $x\in (0,2\sqrt{2})$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Or in other words, $y(x)=(x-8)^2/16$ is not a solution of the differential equation. Indeed it would be the solution that corresponds to the initial condition $y(0)=4$. However, by the slope field you see that this solution can not descend to pass through the point $(1,2)$.[image: The slope field for the equation $y'=x\sqrt{y}$]